# How do I use digital pin on sensor to analog on arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno, pins

I am working on a autonomous fire extinguisher.i have run out of pins.I have the following question in my mind while working on my project

Is it necessary that the DO pin in a flame sensor must be in a PWM digital pin in Arduino.i have this doubt since when I connected it to non PWM pin it didn't worked.

Secondly it is possible for me to use the analog pin in Arduino for the DO pin of the flame sensor or trigger/echo pins of the ultrasonic sensor.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a url/referens to the flame sensor. As it is now it is totaly unclear!

Comment: http://www.theorycircuit.com/arduino-flame-sensor-interface/ I am having sensor having only digital output pin

Comment: @MatsK is it clear now

Answer (score 1):

PWM stands for Puls Width Modulation and is only available when the Digital Pin is in OUTPUT mode.

And **YES**, you can connect the flame sensor's D0 to any digital pin on the Arduino.

And yes it is possible to connect the flame sensor's D0 to a analog pin, but why not use the A0 from the flame sensor and connect it toi a analog pin on the Arduino?

Comment: I have only 3 pin flame sensor

Comment: OK, the one that you refered to is a four pin....

Comment: @MatsK, that site shows both

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analog pins (A0-A5, but not A6 and A7) also as digital pins. So you can set one of them as digital input, connecting it with the D0 pin of your fire sensor. You can read this pin with `digitalRead(pin)`.

Regarding your problem with PWM:
There is no "PWM input" on an Arduino Nano (because PWM hardware in a microcontroller means pulse with modulated output). The example code of your sensor uses an analog input (ADC: Analog Digital Converter) (with usage of `analogRead()`). If you want to use this functionality you have to connect the A0 pin of your sensor to one of A0-A7 and reading it with `analogRead()` to get the fires intensity/distance.

Comment: Will if(digital read(A1)==LOW) work if I connect my DO pin of sensor to analog pin

Comment: The documentation, you linked, says, that it outputs LOW, when nothing is detected and "+Ve" (I guess that means HIGH) when a fire is detected. So to detect the existence of fire use `if(digitalRead(A1)==HIGH)`. But be sure to initialize the pin as input